# Azure: Configuring BlobEndpoint and CloudBlobClient for maximum upload throughput

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm updating a large number of `CloudBlockBlob` using a `CloudBlobClient` per request (it's always the same blob).

The parameters for the the `BlobEndpoint` are set as follows:

```
blobEndpoint.UseNagleAlgorithm<-false
blobEndpoint.ConnectionLimit<-1000
//blobEndpoint.MaxIdleTime<-Timeout.Infinite
```

What I'm noticing is that after a while, the number of updates per second decreases to a very low rate and I suppose it's due to the number of available connections.

Do you recommend using the same blob client for multiple requests with a certain level of parallelism? Maybe a different configuration of the endpoint parameters?

Thanks

EDIT 1:
I did try using a single client across all threads, but the behavior is exactly the same. A very high throughput at first, then the number of connections substantially going down and stabilizing to a very low level. It's like the active connections are not recycled and they are lost by the blob client.

Answer (score 0):

A certain degree of parallelism is necessary to achieve steady high troughput.
See if you can leverage the [**Azure Storage Data Movement library**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-storage-data-movement-library-preview-2/).

```cs
// Use the interfaces from the new Azure Storage Data Movement Library to upload the blob
// Setup the number of the concurrent operations
TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;

// Setup the transfer context and track the upoload progress
TransferContext context = new TransferContext();
context.ProgressHandler = new Progress<TransferProgress>((progress) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred);
});

// Upload a local blob
var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
    sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
task.Wait();
```

It's the stuff [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) is based on, so you know it's serious business.

Comment: I'm using a different CloudBlobClient per request on a rather large number of threads. Are you suggesting using a single client?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set `maxconnection` to 1000 in system.net.

Worked so much better than the `ConnectionLimit` on the blob endpoint.

Comment: Where is this? Your explained property was not found in `System.Net`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/README.md you should configure the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` setting.

The article advices to set it to your number of processors times 8 like so:

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;`

The `CloudBlobClient` class uses an internal `IHttpClient` which uses this setting.